# Как правильно удалить слово Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi

Как удалить все между скобками, включая скобки? Проблема в том, что пробелы расположены по разному:

И как сделать что бы после обработки получился текстовый файл (то есть удалить все между **<>**, включительно, **удаляя лишние пробелы**):

Делаю вот так: но не весь текст обрабатывает правильно:

```
var
    ft, ft2: TextFile;
    i: integer;
    s:string;
Begin

......................................
    while(pos('<',s)>0)and(pos('>',s)>0) do
    Delete(s,Pos('<',s),Pos('>',s)-Pos('<',s)+2);

........................................
```

**Обрабатываетcя вот так:**

Какой хороший(тут пробел)<03.04.2018>сегодня день **После обработки** - Какой хороший егодня день (то есть исчезла буква с в слове сегодня)

Какой хороший(тут пробел)<03.04.2018>(тут пробел)сегодня день **После обработки** в этой строке все отлично, то есть: Какой хороший сегодня день

Какой хороший<03.04.2018>(тут пробел)сегодня день **После обработки** Какой хорошийсегодня день (нет пробела между хороший и сегодня)

**А должны быть все строки вот в таком виде:**

Какой хороший сегодня день

Какой хороший сегодня день

Какой хороший сегодня день

Comment: "но не весь текст обрабатывает правильно" - а КАК неправильно обрабатывается, покажите пример.

Comment: Kromster, Исправила тему и добавила пример.

Comment: Добавьте поконкретнее пожалуйста, пример. Строка на входе, ваша функция, строка на выходе.

Comment: Kromster, Исправила и привела более удобный пример.

Comment: Не `+2`, а `+1`. И после удаления проверять, не оказалось ли в месте удаления два пробела подряд.

Comment: Я бы вам настоятельно рекомендовал ознакомится с [Регулярыми выражениями в Delphi](http://www.webdelphi.ru/2010/09/delphi-xe-rabota-s-regulyarnymi-vyrazheniyami/) а именно вам нужно использовать метод `replace()`

Comment: Уже поняла свою ошибку. Оказывается оказалось действительно два пробела. Благодарна вам за помощь. Прямо сейчас прочту статью по регулярным выражениям.

Comment: Не советую вам ввязываться в регулярки, если в обычном коде у вас худо-бедно что-то получается, то на регулярках нам придется писать все за вас ..

Comment: Kromster, принимаю во внимание ваш совет. Но чисто из любопытства буду в свободное время изучать. Если не учить ничего то тогда буду находиться на прежнем этапе - уровне знаний.

Comment: Kromster, вопрос к вам чисто из любопытства: Не подскажите, а проверять не оказалось ли в месте удаления два пробела подряд, правильно ли я описала это действие: for i:= 1 to Length(s) do
  if s=' ' then delete(s,i,1);

Comment: Татьяна, гораздо проще сделать замену (StringReplace емнип) двух пробелов на один.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать метод `TRegEx.replace()`

Он будет в исходной строке по регулярному выражению заменять на нужное вам 
значение

`TRegEx.replace("исходная строка", "регулярное выражение", "то на что заменяем в вашем случае это пробел")`

И все это будет выглядеть так:
`TRegEx.replace(s, "\s*<.+>\s*", " ")`

Для быстрого написания регулярных выражений могу посоветовать [Ресурс](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Регулярками вырезать одни скобки, когда ТС путается в трех соснах .. сомнительный совет.

Comment: @Kromster Как я понимаю ТС заменять будет не только эти "скобки" ,и по специфике ее работы ей придется сталкиватся с этим часто. И если Татьяна потратит какоето кол-во времени на понимание регулярок решение таких задач станет в разы проще

Comment: @Татьяна получилось использовать регулярные выражения?

Comment: Да, спасибо большое только что как раз удалось сделать.